# Java Regex - Extract link from HTML anchor

Tags: java, regex

I have the following code

```
private String anchorRegex = "\\<\\s*?a\\s+.*?href\\s*?=\\s*?([^\\s]*?).*?\\>";
private Pattern anchorPattern = Pattern.compile(anchorRegex, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
String content = getContentAsString();
Matcher matcher = anchorPattern.matcher(content);

while(matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

The call to `getContentAsString()` returns the HTML content from a web page. The problem I'm having is that the only thing that gets printed in my System.out is a space. Can anyone see what's wrong with my regex?

Regex drives me crazy sometimes.

Comment: It is a bad idea, to do this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not

Comment: He's not matching HTML generally; regex is fine for HTML in constrained use-cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to delimit your capturing group from the following `.*?`. There's probably double quotes `"` around the href, so use those:

```
<\s*a\s+.*?href\s*=\s*"(\S*?)".*?>
```

Your regex contains:

```
([^\s]*?).*?
```

The `([^\s]*?)` says to reluctantly find all non-whitespace characters and save them in a group. But the reluctant `*?` depends on the next part, which is `.`; any character. So the matching of the href aborts at the first possible chance and it is the `.*?` which matches the rest of the URL.

Comment: I thought about that but the problem I found is that some sites may use single quotes in the href, while some may omit both single and double quotes.

Comment: Single vs. double quotes is easy; use `['"]`, but if the site is not delimiting the `href` from other attributes, they should go to hell and you should not bother with them or their data. E.g. what do you expect from this: `<a href=a class=.html>` ? If you really need information from horribly formatted HTML, you should use something other than a regex.

Answer (score 1):

The regex you should be using is this:

```
String anchorRegex = "(?s)<\\s*a\\s+.*?href\\s*=\\s*['\"]([^\\s>]*)['\"]";
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be able to pull out the href without too much trouble.
The link is in capture group 2, its expanded and assumes dot-all.
Use Java delimiters as necessary.

```
(?s)
<a 
  (?=\s) 
  (?:[^>"']|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')*? (?<=\s) href \s*=\s* (['"]) (.*?) \1 
  (?:".*?"|'.*?'|[^>]*?)+ 
>
```

or not expanded, not dot-all.

`<a(?=\s)(?:[^>"']|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')*?(?<=\s)href\s*=\s*(['"])([\s\S]*?)\1(?:"[\s\S]*?"|'[\s\S]*?'|[^>]*?)+>`